# 英語が残っている: 次の権限獲得までの進捗: Next privilege とその権限の説明

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

URL: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

[image: Next privilege]

1. Next privilege というラベル
2. その権限の内容説明 "access review queues"

Comment: すべての権限のリストをまとめようとしています。翻訳済ですが、あまりにも日本語の違和感が多いと思いますので、同時に権限の用語を決めましょう。しばらくお待ちください。

Comment: status-completedになってますが"access review queues"は英語のまま残っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

それでは"Next privilege"だけ:

> 次の権限獲得まで

はめこんで見た:

[image: 次の権限獲得まで]

Comment: Privilege名はまだ把握していませんが、「Next privilege」の和訳を適用しました。